# Preposition: unter vs. an

Tags: preposition

Bei folgendem Beispiel ist die Version 1 mit der Präposition *an* richtig. Ich finde allerdings, dass die Variante 2 logischer ist, denn die Lampe soll ja **unter** die Stelle, um die es geht, gehängt werden?

Weshalb ist es trotzdem an?

**Hier folgt das Beispiel:**

> Haben Sie schon die Lampe im Wohnzimmer aufgehängt?

**Version 1**:

> Nein, denn die alte Lampe, die davor **an** dieser Stelle gehangen hat, hat eine komplizierte Aufhängung.

**Version 2**:

> Nein, denn die alte Lampe, die davor **unter** dieser Stelle gehangen hat, hat eine komplizierte Aufhängung.

Comment: *Hängen* wird die Lampe wohl schon **unter** dem Haken. *Angehängt* ist sie aber **am** Haken (Wenn man sie da anhängt, wo sie nacher *ist* fällt sie runter. Ausser man gönnt sich den Luxus eines "Siemens-Lufthakens" (http://www.stupidedia.org/stupi/Siemens_Lufthaken)

Comment: @tofro +1 für den Lufthaken der Firma Siemens ;)

Comment: Dass es da nicht mittlerweile günstigere Nachbauten gibt...

Comment: Aber die können qualitativ mit dem Siemens-Lufthaken einfach nicht konkurrieren.

Answer (score 4):

Erste Gegenfrage: Würdest Du bei einem Deckenfluter auch sagen, er steht über einer Stelle? Oder würdest Du nicht davon sprechen, dass der Deckenfluter **an** einer ungünstigen Stelle steht?

Das Objekt *Lampe* (=> der leuchtende Teil) hängt natürlich im Normalfall **unter** ihrer Aufhängung, aber die Aufhängung selbst hängt **an** einer Stelle an der Decke (genauso, wie der leuchtende Teil **an** der Aufhängung hängt (= daran festgemacht ist).

Wenn man davon spricht, eine Lampe aufzuhängen, bezieht man sich (auch wenn man Lampe sagt) implizit auf den Punkt, an dem die Halterung festgemacht wird.

Eine Lampe hängt also **unter** der Decke. Aufgehängt ist sie aber **an** der Decke. Und damit hängt die Lampe auch **an** der Decke.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Ausführungen. Zur Gegenfrage: Logischer würde mir erscheinen, wenn der Deckenfluter **auf** einer ungünstigen Stelle stehen würde.

Answer (score 1):

### an dieser Stelle

> F: Kann ich die neue Lampe jetzt schon dort an der Wand montieren wo du den Strich gemacht hast?
>   A: *Nein, denn die alte Lampe, die davor **an dieser Stelle** gehangen hat, hat eine komplizierte Aufhängung.* Die neue Aufhängung ist zwar simpler, aber mir fehlen trotzdem die passenden Schrauben. Die muss ich erst besorgen, dann kannst du sie dort aufhängen.

Das bedeutet:

Die alte Lampe war genau ***an*** dieser Stelle befestigt die jetzt mit einem Strich markiert ist, und hing von diesem Befestigungspunkt nach unten.

Das Wörtchen »***an***« informiert den Leser oder Zuhörer darüber, dass die Befestigung genau ***an*** der bezeichneten Stelle erfolgt, nicht irgendwo anders.

Dass die Lampe mehr Raum einnimmt als nur den Befestigungspunkt, ist jedermann klar. Ebenso ist klar, dass aus den Worten »*hängen*« oder »*aufhängen*« folgt, dass sich die Lampe selbst direkt unterhalb des Aufhängepunktes befindet.

---

### unter dieser Stelle

> F: Kann ich die neue Lampe jetzt schon dort an der Wand montieren wo du den Strich gemacht hast?
>   A: *Nein, denn die alte Lampe, die davor **unter dieser Stelle** gehangen hat, hat eine komplizierte Aufhängung.* Die neue Aufhängung ist zwar simpler, aber mir fehlen trotzdem die passenden Schrauben. Die muss ich erst besorgen, dann kannst du sie dort aufhängen.

Das bedeutet:

Die neue Lampe soll etwas oberhalb jener Stelle montiert werden, an der früher die alte Lampe befestigt war.

Das Wörtchen »***unter***« besagt *nicht*, dass die Lampe vom Befestigungspunkt ausgehend nach unten hängt. Tatsächlich sagt das Wort aus, dass sich der Befestigungspunkt ***unter*** (also ausdrücklich ***nicht an***) der genannten Stelle befindet.

> Die alte Lampe hing **unter der Stelle**, die ich markiert habe.
>   Wie weit darunter hing sie?
>   Sie hing genau 30 cm **unter der markierten Stelle**.

Answer (score 0):

Solche "weshalb?"-Fragen haben keine besonders große Aussicht auf einen entscheidenden Erkenntnisgewinn - Die einzig mögliche richtige Antwort darauf ist nämlich:

> Weil viele Menschen über viele Jahre hinweg die Erfahrung gemacht haben, dass sie verstanden werden, wenn sie sich so ausdrücken.

Das ist nämlich der Haupttreiber für die Entwicklung und Fortentwicklung von Sprache. Sprache ist fast nie *so genau wie möglich*, sondern nur so *genau wie nötig*.

Noch mehr "unlogische" Beispiele gefällig?

Natürlich hängt das Bild nicht an der Wand - sondern am Nagel.

Und jeden zweiten Morgen auf dem Weg zur Arbeit fragt mich jemand: "Wann kommt die Strassenbahn?" - Woher soll ich das wissen? - auf dem Fahrplan stehen nur die *Abfahrts*zeiten.

Oder anders ausgedrückt: Solange *die Nase läuft und die Füße riechen* hat es keinen Sinn, einer Sprache mit Logik beikommen zu wollen.

Comment: Ach, wenn es um Züge ginge: Dort sind auch Ankunftszeiten ausgehängt. Wobei das die Frage nicht beantwortet; es wäre ja höchstens die Antwort auf die Frage »Wann *soll* der Zug kommen?« ;)

Comment: @Jan Möglicherweise hab' ich mir ja was gedacht, als ich "Strassenbahn" geschrieben habe ;)

Comment: Etwas *gedacht* bei einer Antwort?! Nicht möglich! =O